# Unable to update per page count from the frontend (Laravel, InertiaJS, VueJS)

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am migrating my current application from Laravel Livewire to Laravel InertiaJS VueJS. Currently I am stuck at setting the per page count from the front end and paginate the data accordingly. Currently I am using Laravel's default pagination along with the custom pagination component for VueJS and it works seamlessly. I just want to set the `$per_page` as per the input, the variable is set to 5 by default, in the index method of the controller. Below is the code structure and the logic. Please help me achieve this in the way InertiaJS is meant to be used.

[image]

UserController.php

```
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $per_page = \Request::get('per_page') ?: 5;

        $query = User::select('id', 'name', 'email', 'role_id', 'created_at');
        $users = $query->paginate($per_page);

        return Inertia::render('Backend/Management/AudienceManagement/Users/Index', [
            'users' => $users
        ]);
    }
```

Users/Index.vue

```
<template>
    <input-group borderless paddingless inline>
        <input-select @change="setPerPage($event)" id="perPage" placeholder="Per Page">
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </input-select>
    </input-group>
</template>

<script>
    import {
        Inertia
    } from '@inertiajs/inertia'

    export default {
        props: {
            users: {
                type: Object
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                sortField: '',
                sortDirection: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            setPerPage(event) {
                console.log(event.target.value);
                this.users.per_page = event.target.value;
                Inertia.reload({
                    only: ['users.data']
                });
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```